# bash & sed: replace password on string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script running some command having a readeable password as parameter:

```
#/bin/bash
batch.sh --user=stefano --option=read-only --password=my_password_very_secret
batch.sh --password=password --user=dummy --option=abc
batch.sh --option=abc --user=dummy2 --password=whatever
batch.sh --user=dummy3 --password=12345
```

The batch.sh script performs some action and write a log file with command itself and output of it.

On this log I would like that the password value would be overridden with "hidden" (or "*********") string.

The fastest but probably not cleanest solution that I've found is the following one...

```
Script: batch.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a log" > /path/to/log/file.txt
echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's|password=\(.*\)|password=********|' | tr '\n' ' ' >> /path/to/log/file.txt
echo "Completed" >> /path/to/log/file.txt
```

...but I'm almost sure that's not the most elegant approach.
How else I can write it differently?

The expected output on log file create should be something like

```
This is a log
batch.sh --user=stefano --option=read-only --password=********
batch.sh --password=******** --user=dummy --option=abc
batch.sh --option=abc --user=dummy2 --password=********
batch.sh --user=dummy3 --password=********
Completed
```

Comment: Yes I can change it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bash script should look like this:

```
sed 's/password=[^[:space:]]*/password=****** /g' <<< "$@" >> logfile
```

However, passing a password on the command line is never a good idea. The command line arguments are visible using the `ps` command or via `/proc/PID/cmdline`.

Comment: I definetively agree with you that using password on command line is not a good idea as they can be queried throgh ps command, but nobody (apart me) has the grant to connect to the host via ssh or telnet. Users, instead, has grants to read logs created by bash script through ftp and nfs. For this reasons, I have to warn users that command has been triggered but I don't want that any users could read any password.
So wrote, your solution is very elegant and suitable for my needs!

Comment: What if your shell script reads the password from a configuration file? This should be possible.

Comment: you're definetively right. It would be much more better. Thanks for suggestion!